# How to blank the hidden field value from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume that a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" name="hdn" value="100" />
```

So i want to blank the value of hidden field using Jquery. 
In javascript we can blank using this syntax

```
document.getElementById("hdn").value = '';
```

but i want it using jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#hdn").val("");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val